# How to get Universal time if my computer is not showing correct time with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, time

I am developing a desktop application in vb.net

I am facing a problem.

If my computer's time is not correct , then how can i get correct universal time ?

Comment: There are public time servers (google for that) and the `ntp` protocol to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38276/An-SNTP-Client-for-C-and-VB-NET
to set the correct time on the computer.